# Is `Gtk.Window.set_attached_to` really the correct way to position a popup relative to a widget in wayland?

Tags: python, popup, gtk, gtk3, wayland

[`set_attached_to`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Window.html#Gtk.Window.set_attached_to) seems to be the correct way to position a popup window relative to a widget in wayland:

> Examples of places where specifying this relation is useful are for instance [...] a completion popup window created by Gtk.Entry [...]

Unfortunately this only yields an error

> Gdk-Message: 12:13:16.143: Window 0x1822340 is a temporary window without parent, application will not be able to position it on screen.

Trying to uncomment the `popup.set_parent(entry)` line only adds a warning:

> (try_entry_popup.py:4539): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:17:34.185: Can't set a parent on a toplevel widget

followed by the same error.

Here is a minimal example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# stripped down from https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/1541#note_396391

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

entry = Gtk.Entry()
popup = Gtk.Window(type=Gtk.WindowType.POPUP)
#popup.set_parent(entry)
popup.set_attached_to(entry)
popup.show_all()

layout = Gtk.VBox()
layout.pack_start(entry, False, True, 0)

window = Gtk.Window()
window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
window.add(layout)
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

From the [entry completion source](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/blob/075dcc142aa525778268165095de019b736f3efa/gtk/gtkentrycompletion.c#L2729) it looks like it definitely should work.
Is it using private features ? Or what am I missing ?

Comment: Tested on lubuntu-19.04, gnome wayland session (gtk 3.24.8, gdk backend: wayland)

Comment: Replace with `popup.add(layout)`

Comment: @stovfl That achieved nothing, of course, except blocking the terminal.

Comment: Have you removed: `window.add(layout)`?

Comment: @stovfl Yes. Did you try ?

Comment: gtk_window_set_attached_to has nothing to do with positioning, it's important for accessibility (a11y) and to apply theming in a correct way. If you want to position your popup window you can follow what it's done in https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/blob/075dcc142aa525778268165095de019b736f3efa/gtk/gtkentrycompletion.c#L1597

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, not really: gtk_window_set_attached_to has nothing to do with positioning, it's important for accessibility (a11y) and to apply theming in a correct way. If you want to position your popup window you can follow what it's done in https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/blob/075dcc142aa525778268165095de019b736f3efa/gtk/gtkentrycompletion.c#L1597

Here's a very simple implementation:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

def on_button_clicked(widget):
  popup = Gtk.Window(type=Gtk.WindowType.POPUP)
  # optionally you may set an appropriate type hint, but it's not required.
  popup.set_attached_to(entry)
  popup.set_transient_for(window)

  gdk_window = entry.get_window()
  gdk_window_origin = gdk_window.get_origin()
  x = gdk_window_origin[1]
  y = gdk_window_origin[2]
  allocation = entry.get_allocation()
  x += allocation.x
  y += allocation.y + allocation.height

  popup.move(x, y)
  popup.show_all()

button = Gtk.Button()
button.connect('clicked', on_button_clicked)
entry = Gtk.Entry()
layout = Gtk.VBox()
layout.pack_start(button, False, True, 0)
layout.pack_start(entry, False, True, 0)

window = Gtk.Window()
window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
window.add(layout)
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Comment: So the answer is "not at all", thanks ! I have misread "Note that this function should not be confused with Gtk.Window.set_transient_for(), which specifies a window manager relation between two toplevels instead." `set_attached_to` is *not* the window/widget equivalent of the window/window `set_transient_for`.

Comment: Unfortunately the errors are still there, and the popup is not correctly positioned. But that is another question. Thanks !

Comment: Yeah, for now I have tested only on Xorg and there were no errors. I will also try on Wayland

Comment: Hello! I have tried on Wayland and updated the answer. To get rid of the runtime warning and to position the popup correctly you have to call set_transient_for. The [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-transient-for) explains why that's necessary on Wayland. That's useful on other backends, too.